# Building periodic sequences from finite-support sequences

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, python, periodic

Given a discrete-time finite-support signal x[n]

$$x[n] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{{{( - 1)}^n}n}&{{\rm{ }}n = 1,2,3}\\
0&{{\rm{otherwise}}}
\end{array}} \right.$$

And consider also its periodic repetition is

$$y[n] = \sum\nolimits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {x[n + 7k]} $$

How we can generate the y[n] in Matlab or Python?

Here is piece of code to generate and plot x[n]. But for Y[n] I have no idea!

```
% finite support signal
n = -5:1:8;
x = zeros(size(n));
x( find(n==1 | n==2 | n==3) ) = [(-1)^1*1 (-1)^2*2 (-1)^3*3];
stem(n, x, 'filled')
```

Comment: Hint: think about what `mod(n,7)` might do for you.

Comment: Thank you for comment. $x(mod(n,7)+1)$ produces the periodic extension of x[n]: $y[n]=x[n\space mod\space 7]$. @Florian

Comment: @Florian Now the question is, $y[n] = \sum\nolimits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {x[n + 7k]}$ is equivalent to  $y[n]=x[n\space mod\space 7]$?

Comment: Do you see any reason why it shouldn't be the same? I suggest you write out $y[n]$ for a few examples, this should make it easier to see it. Like $y[1] = x[1]+x[8]+x[15]+...+x[-6]+x[-13]+...$ Then use the fact that $x[n]$ is zero almost everywhere...

Comment: @Florian Cloud you please check answer I've posted?

Comment: @Florian As the $k$ increases the values of $y$ become larger and larger. So what we can say about signal $y[n]$? What we can say about its energy and powers based on the result obtained as below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking too complicated. Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my comment.

You're given a sequence $x[n]$ that contains three spikes and zeros elsewhere. Your sequence $y[n]$ contains periodically shifted copies of the original one. It's just repeating the same three spikes indefinitely, without overlap since $7>3$. Hence, all you need to do to find out what $y[n]$ is for a given $n$ is to check where it would map to in your original sequence. In other words: $$y[n] = x[n \; {\rm mod} \; 7].$$

Here is how you can see why that is true: take $y[n] = \sum_k x[n+7k]$, expand, and then use the fact that $x[n]$ is zero outside $[0,7)$ (in fact, zero outside $[1,2,3]$):

$$\begin{align}y[0] & = x[0] + x[7] + x[14] + \ldots + x[-7] + x[-14] + \ldots = x[0] \\
y[1] & = x[1] + x[8] + x[15] + \ldots + x[-6] + x[-13] + \ldots = x[1]\\
& \ldots\\
y[6] & = x[6] + x[13] + x[20] + \ldots + x[-1] + x[-8] + \ldots = x[6] \\
y[7] & = x[7] + x[14] + x[15] + \ldots + x[0] + x[-7] + \ldots = x[0] \\
y[8] & = \ldots = x[1] \\
& \ldots \\
y[13] & = \ldots = x[6] \\
y[14] & = \ldots = x[0] \\
\end{align}$$

And that's how I would do it in Matlab

```
x = @(n) (-1).^n .* n .* ((n>=1)&(n<=3));
y = @(n) x(mod(n,7));
n = -7:21;
figure(1);clf;stem(n,x(n))
hold on;
stem(n,y(n),'rx--')
xlabel('n');axis([-7,21,-4,4])
legend('x[n]','y[n]');
```

***edit**: Regarding your question 1: yes, you can do it with a sum as well. If you do it correctly, the result is exactly the same. Here's a take in Matlab: Of course you cannot do an infinite sum, so this example sums from `-K` to `K`, plotting for `K=10`:

```
x = @(n) (-1).^n .* n .* ((n>=1)&(n<=3));
y = @(n) x(mod(n,7));
y_sum = @(n,K) sum(x(n + 7*(-K:K)'),1);
n = -7:21;
figure(1);clf;stem(n,x(n))
hold on;
stem(n,y(n),'rx--')
stem(n,y_sum(n,10),'k*-.')
xlabel('n');axis([-7,21,-4,4])
legend('x[n]','y[n]');
```

[image: Matlab example, revised]

Regarding your second question, well, the code is there, you can experiment with what changes. If the pulses overlap, you're going to see the sums of the overlapping ones... in particular the -1 and the -3 pulse add up to -4 pulses. Looks like this (now the modulo method does not work like that, since it assumed no overlap):

[image: Matlab example with overlap]

Comment: Merci for answer. I have some questions ...

Comment: 1- We can build y[n] by superimposing (adding) infinite copies of x[n]. Ok? So, what the answer I've posted represent?
Are superimposing and adding are two different operator in DSP?

Comment: 2- If we take k=2 instead of 7, then copies in the sum do overlap. Now what are the values of y[n]?

Comment: @sci9 I edited my reply to account for your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. But there is still one question left unanswered. Does the answer I've posted have some meaning? @Florian

Comment: @sci9 Not really - in your answer you're mixing the modulo solution with computing sums, in a way that doesn't make sense to me. You can see that the result is wrong, since the amplitudes are growing, which they should not. It's $y[n] = x[n \; {\rm mod} \; 7]$, not $y[n] = \sum_k x[n \; {\rm mod} \; 7]$.

Comment: Merci, Is there cases in which building periodic signals causes growing in amplitudes?  Is it physically reachable to generate periodic signals with growing amplitudes from a finite-length finite-support signal?

Comment: Not really. In the discrete case the extreme would be periodifying with a period of 1 sample: in this case you'd get a constant signal, its amplitudes being equal to the sum of the amplitudes in your original signal. You can't go lower than that with the period. I mean, technically, you could set it to zero, but I say that's meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Florian's comments, here is sample solution

```
clc, clear
n = 0:1:7*10^6-1;
x = zeros(size(n));
x( find(n==1 | n==2 | n==3) ) = [(-1)^1*1 (-1)^2*2 (-1)^3*3];
y = x(mod(n,7)+1);
y = sum(reshape(y,7,[]),2)'
```

For large $k$s we have for example: `y = 0    -1000000     2000000    -3000000           0           0           0`.